# Neo4j persistent named graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher, named-graphs

I'm coming from the RDF world where named graphs are persistent and can be used like a collection of triples. Moreover you can query against one single named graph or over the whole triplestore. I'm looking for the same features (or a workaround to achive them) in Neo4j.

Neo4j's Graph Catalog is well [documented](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/management-ops/graph-catalog-ops/). As I understood, named graphs in Neo4j are stored entirely in-memory (so lost after a restart) with a subset of nodes you define for analytic purpose.

Is there a way to create persistents named graphs in Neo4j?
A graph that is stored in the disk with the data and that permits to fast access to a subset of nodes (nodes can be added or removed from the named graph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give every node in the same "named graph" the same [label](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-labels). Since a node can have multiple labels, this does not prevent you from using other labels for other purposes as well.